# how do i over put something in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a modal and I need to place the modal above

```js
let buttonOpen = document.querySelector(".button-open");
let buttonClose = document.querySelector(".button-close");
let modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.classList.add("show-modal");
});

buttonClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.classList.remove("show-modal");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* for open the modal*/

#container {
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.show-modal {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- for open the modal -->
<div id="container">
  <button class="button-open">Open Modal</button>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h3>Title a modal</h3>
    <button class="button-close">Close Modal</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

photo the result:

[image]

and I want the box to be on top of the content
so that it is not below the content but above it, as if it were a layer above my real page content

Comment: Maybe check out `position: fixed`?

Comment: Yeah, in the class ``show-modal``, but didn't work

Comment: `position: absolute`, `position: relative`, `position: fixed` will all work. Given that you've made the container take up the whole screen, I suggest the first.

Comment: If you don't want the modal to take up the whole screen, you can try adding `position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;` to the `.modal` or `.show-modal` classes.